# I need to manipulate a line that can rotate in (-1,7) right where the dashed arrow touches the blue line by changing the direction of the red arrow

Tags: graphics, manipulate, vector

`Graphics[{{Blue, Line[{{-5, 3}, {5, 8}}]}, {Dashed,  Arrow[{{0, 0}, P}]}, Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, v}]}, Axes -> True,  AxesLabel -> {x, y}]`
I've tried combining Graphics and Plot to manipulate my graphic but it says that I can't.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not entirely sure if this is what you're asking for, but maybe it'll point in you a useful direction.

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    {InfiniteLine[point, {1, Tan[angle]}], 
     {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, 2 {Cos@angle, Sin@angle}}]}, 
     {Red, PointSize[.03], Point[point]}, 
     {Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0}, point}]}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Axes -> True],
  {{angle, Pi/4}, 0, 10},
  Control[{{point, {-1, 1}}, {-10, -10}, {10, 10}}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{Blue, line = InfiniteLine[{{-5, 3}, {5, 8}}]}, {Dashed, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, 
      RegionIntersection[line, 
        InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, 
         RotationMatrix[\[Pi]/6] . v]][[1]]}]}, {Red, 
    Arrow[{{0, 0}, v}]}}, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-2, 10}}, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {{v, 2 Normalize@{0, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, 
  Locator, TrackingFunction -> {v = 2 Normalize@#; &}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
P = {-1, 5};
v = {2, 1};
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{{Blue, 
    GeometricTransformation[InfiniteLine[{{-5, 3}, {5, 8}}], 
     RotationTransform[
      ArcTan[vv[[1]], vv[[2]]] - VectorAngle[{1, 0}, v], 
      P]]}, {Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0}, P}]}, Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, vv}]}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2.5, 9}}], {{vv, v}, Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> {vv = Norm[v] Normalize@#; &}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much